# Woocommerce cadastro de clientes

Tags: wordpress, login, woocommerce

Pessoal estou com um projeto onde preciso customizar o formulário de cadastro do Woocommerce, o mesmo ja possui email e senha. Porém preciso adicionar o campo CNPJ e validar se ele é verdadeiro, E está informação deve aparecer também na página de detalhes da conta.

Preciso fazer com quem somente cadastre em meu site com CNPJ possa ter acesso a preços e tudo mais, porém não consigo colocar a opção de CNPJ obrigatório no cadastro.

Alguém sabe se isso é possível ? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi @Marcos.

Com certeza dá sim. Tem um artigo legal aqui: https://iconicwp.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-adding-custom-woocommerce-user-account-fields/

Dá uma olhada! Talvez você consiga formular uma dúvida mais específica.

Comment: Para quem precisa de uma ajudinha, da uma olhada nesse artigo que Leonel Costa Braz compartilhou comigo. Muito bom, obrigado pela ajuda, era exatamente isso que eu precisava !